# How to define doctrine record filter in symfony's schema.yml?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, schema.yml

Doctrine documentation explains that in order to add doctrine record filter, you have to unshiftFilter() to table definition setUp() method:

```
public function setUp(){
    parent::setUp();
    $this->unshiftFilter(new MyDoctrineRecordFilter());
}
```

In symfony's case that supposed to go to base class (i.e. /lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseArticle.class.php) but as symfony overwrites base classes every time i rebuild the schema - how (or where) should i define that filter so it would appear there after running the doctrine:build command? I can't find any reference in doc or internet about it's definition in schema.yml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using doctrine 1.2.4. It seems that there is no yaml-schema equivalent

Answer (score 0):

As you've learned, never make any changes to automatically generated *base* classes. Your changes will just be wiped away.

Instead, you'll find child classes that extend your base classes. Symfony/Doctrine won't touch those once they are created (with the exception of `symfony doctrine:clean-model-files`). In your case, look for:

```
/lib/model/doctrine/Article.class.php
```

Form Filters are defined similarly on a different path:

```
/lib/filter/doctrine/base/BaseArticleFormFilter.class.php
/lib/filter/doctrine/ArticleFormFilter.class.php
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I'm aware of that. Tried to add the setup function to Article.class.php:

public function setUp(){
  parent::setUp();
        $this->unshiftFilter(new MyDoctrineRecordFilter());
}

 but then i get error when trying to rebuild the schema: Fatal error: Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in C:\projects\myproject\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php on line 1239.

Note that MyDoctrineRecordFilter is not formfilter, but doctrine record filter (extends Doctrine_Record_Filter).